# When can we expect React's new Time-Slicing Asynchronous rendering feature?

Tags: reactjs

Like stated in Dan Abramov: Beyond React 16 | JSConf Iceland 2018.

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLF0n9SACd4][1]

Comment: Likely when this issue is closed, https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### sync-async-debounced (React Time Slicing example)

After I have seen Dan Abramov's presentation [Beyond React 16](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLF0n9SACd4) in JSConf Iceland 2018 I was interested in Time Slicing. I tried to create an application that was shown in the presentation. That made me to study the React code and especially [Scheduler](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/scheduler/src/Scheduler.js) package.

Scheduler package is still in the early stages of development and I do not know which direction to go, but it is definitely a useful improvement of the react library (framework?).
I will try to be up to date with the development. It is currently compliant with version 16.7.0

Demo: https://btraljic.github.io/sync-async-debounced/
GitHub repo: https://github.com/btraljic/sync-async-debounced

At first, I used `unstable_scheduleCallback`:

```
unstable_scheduleCallback(() => { 
  this.setState({ chars }); 
});
```

(`chars` contain string length that determines the complexity of the charts)

Time Slicing worked properly, but, for this example, with unnecessary schedule render. In the example, we are only interested in the last state of the charts. So, I upgraded the logic using `unstable_getFirstCallbackNode` and `unstable_cancelCallback` and eliminated unnecessary rendering:

```
const firstNode = unstable_getFirstCallbackNode(); 

if (firstNode) { 
  unstable_cancelCallback(firstNode); 
}

unstable_scheduleCallback(() => { 
  this.setState({ chars }); 
});
```

I will try to track the development of Time Slicing. Feel free to join.